# Shiny tableOutput some rows in scientific notation and others in percent format

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that outputs tables from a list of data frames using renderTable. A minimal example is shown below. I want the output table to have some rows output in scientific notation and the other rows output in percent format. How would I go about doing this?

```
library(shiny)

# create dummy CSVs -------------------------------------------------------
DF1 <- data.frame(x = c(1.1, 2.1, 3.4), y = c(5.6, 4.2, 6.7))
DF2 <- data.frame(x = c(2.4, 6.7, 8.9), y = c(4.1, 6.3, 8.4))
DF3 <- data.frame(x = c(3.5, 9.5, 3.2), y = c(1.4, 4.5, 7.2))
DF4 <- data.frame(x = c(2.1, 7.4, 8.2), y = c(1.5, 7.2, 6.2))

mapply(
  write.csv,
  x = list(DF1, DF2, DF3, DF4),
  file = list("DF1.csv", "DF2.csv", "DF3.csv", "DF4.csv"),
  row.names = FALSE
)

# shiny app ---------------------------------------------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput(
      "files",
      "Choose File",
      multiple = TRUE,
      accept = c(
        "text/csv",
        "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
        ".dp_txt",
        ".is_txt"
      )
    ),
    selectizeInput(
      inputId = "selected_table",
      label = "Table Selection",
      choices = NULL,
      selected = NULL,
      multiple = FALSE
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(tableOutput("table"))
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$files, {
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "selected_table")
    updateSelectizeInput(session,
                         inputId = "selected_table",
                         choices = input$files$name,
                         server = TRUE)
  })
  
  table_list <- reactive({
    req(input$files)
    setNames(lapply(input$files$datapath, function(x) {
      fread(x)
    }),
    input$files$name)
  })
  
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    req(table_list(), input$selected_table)
    table_list()[[input$selected_table]]
  }, server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I know I can use the base R `format()` function to convert rows to scientific notation and can also use the `label_percent()` from the `scales` package to convert rows to percent format. I have not yet found a way to mix these format changes in the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably multiple approaches to achieve your desired result (and probably more efficient ones than my code below which uses `lapply` to loop over the columns and do the formatting of the rows. As you haven't specified which rows you want to format how I formatted row 1 in scientific and rows 2 to 3 in percent format:

Note: I dropped all the file input stuff to make the reprex a minimal reproducible example.

```r
library(shiny)

DF1 <- data.frame(x = c(1.1, 2.1, 3.4), y = c(5.6, 4.2, 6.7))
DF2 <- data.frame(x = c(2.4, 6.7, 8.9), y = c(4.1, 6.3, 8.4))
DF3 <- data.frame(x = c(3.5, 9.5, 3.2), y = c(1.4, 4.5, 7.2))
DF4 <- data.frame(x = c(2.1, 7.4, 8.2), y = c(1.5, 7.2, 6.2))

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("selected_table", "Select a table", paste0("DF", 1:4))  
  ),
  mainPanel(tableOutput("table"))
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  table_list <- reactive({
    setNames(list(DF1, DF2, DF3, DF4), paste0("DF", 1:4))
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    req(table_list(), input$selected_table)
    tbl <- table_list()[[input$selected_table]]
    
    to_scientific <- 1
    to_percent <- 2:3
    
    lapply(tbl, function(x) {
      xx <- x
      xx[to_scientific] <- scales::scientific(x[to_scientific])
      xx[to_percent] <- scales::percent(x[to_percent], scale = 1)
      xx
    })
    
  }, server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8112
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>